# How to prevent Google One Tap from stealing the focus from an input?

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-signin, autofocus, google-one-tap

If you use [Google One Tap](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/display-google-one-tap) on a page which has an `input` or `textarea` with `autofocus`, or where you use `focus()` during the page load, Google One Tap removes the focus from the input field when it displays its login window.

This looks like a Google One Tap bug to me.

Is there a way to avoid it?  And to report it?

Answer (score 1):

Agreed, this really should be configurable behaviour.

I mitigated it with:

```js
window.addEventListener("blur", (_e) => setTimeout(() => window.focus(), 0))
```